# How do I display a list and a list of lists side by side

Tags: c#, list, linq, nested-lists

I found a code that displays two lists side by side but a list and a list of lists no luck

this is the code of two lists side by side

```
for (var i = 0; i < bncount; i++)
{
  //Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0,-10} | {1,-10}", hed.ElementAt(i),bin.ElementAt(i)));
  Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0,-10} | {1,-10}", i< hdcount ? hed[i] : string.Empty, i< bncount ? bin[i] : string.Empty));          
}
```

but the string.empty is for lists only and not list of lists and ElementAt() also wouldn't work
I tried using linq with foreach but no success

the hed is a list of strings and bn is a list of lists of a sequence of numbers

my output are as follows

```
foreach(var r in bin) //0010 1110 1111
foreach(var m in hed) //red blue white
```

I want to have the following output

```
red 0010
blue 1110
white 1111
```

or

```
red   blue  white
 0     1      1     
 0     1      1     
 1     1      1
 0     0      1
```

Any Idea on how to do this in c# in general or in Linq? the methods I tried either resulted on reprinting one value only froma hed and all the vlaues from bin or the opposite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understood the question correctly, I think it would be helpful to extend the code examples including the variables definition. Anyway, if I understood correctly, this would me my approach:

```
var listOfString = new List<string>( )
{
    "red",
    "blue",
    "white"
};

var listOfArrays = new List<int[]>( )
{
    new int[] { 0,0,1,0 },
    new int[] { 0,1,1,1 },
    new int[] { 1,1,1,1 }
};

// Here you could add a condition in case you are not 100% sure your arrays are of same length.
for( var i = 0; i < listOfString.Count; i++ )
{
    var stringItem = listOfString[i];
    var arrayItem = listOfArrays[i];

    Console.WriteLine( $"{stringItem} {string.Join( null, arrayItem )}" );
}
```

Comment: Much appreciated it works, I was afraid it would throw me the same error of not outputting the result but System.Collections.Generic.List... but the output was as the 1st example I mentioned. Regarding the 2nd one I will try to see how to position it but if you have an idea I would like to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a different structure for storing your data (considering OOP principles) and the following code for printing the data out:

```
public class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<int> Values { get; set; }
}

public void Print(List<Item> items)
{
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{item.Name} {string.Join("", item.Values)}");
    }
}
```

Comment: I have them already defined cause I read them from a file, That's why I can't consider a different structure or approach

Answer (score 0):

The first version is not so hard:

```
string reuslt = string.Join("\n", bin.Zip(hed).Select(x => $"{x.Item1} {x.Item2}"));
```

With zip, we create an enumerable of tuples, where the n-th tuple has the n-th element of bin and the n-th element of hed. You can just concatenate those two items.

The second version is a bit more complex:

```
result = string.Join("\t",hed) + "\n" + 
       string.Join("\n",Enumerable.Range(0, bin.First().Length)
             .Select(x => string.Join("\t\t", bin.Select(str => str[x]))));
```

We create the heading line by just joing the hed strings. Then we create an enumerable of numbers which represent the indexes in the string. The enumerable will be 0, 1, 2, 3. Then we take the char with index 0 of each string of the bin list, then the char with index 1 of each string of the bin list and so on.

Online demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/eBQ54N

Comment: I actually found out about zip just a minute ago and when I implemented it the binary result was outputting System.Collections.Generic.List'1[System.String] using this code var resultsequence = hed.Zip(bin, (first, second) => first + " - " + second); and when I also tried implementing yours I had a probleme with the Zip method until  removed the Select part and replaced it with second) => first + " - " + second that it removed the error but still outputted the same

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary:

```
        var hed = new List<string>(){"red", "blue", "white"};
        var bin = new List<string>(){ "0010", "1110", "1111" };
        Dictionary<string, string> Dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < hed.Count; i++)
        {
            Dic.Add(hed[i],bin[i]);
        }

        foreach (var item in Dic)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Key+" "+item.Value);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: the hed and bin variables are already defined and bin is defined as list of lists so using your approach will need to convert bin into a single list which isn't doable